# How to extract the average of rows from a file using another range file as a map

Tags: r, range

I have one object like this:

```
file1 <-"Chr Pos DepthAverage Dispersion
chr1  1    5  4
chr1  2    4  1
chr1  3    5  3
chr1  4    7  9
chr1  5    4  8
chr1  6    3  2
chr2  1    1  3
chr2  2    1  4
chr2  3    3  3"
file1<-read.table(text=file1,header=T)
```

And another that is a "range" file like this:

```
file2 <-"Chr  Start  End
chr1  1  4
chr1  5  6
chr2  1  2
chr2  3  3"
file2<-read.table(text=file2,header=T)
```

And I want a "range file" from file2 with columns "Depth Average" and "Dispersion" coming from the average of the rows within this interval on file1.
Follows the exemple:

```
  file3 <-"Chr Start End DepthAverage Dispersion
  chr1 1 4 5.25 4.25
  chr1 5 6 3.5 5
  chr2 1 2 1 3.5
  chr2 3 3 3 3"
  file3<-read.table(text=file3,header=T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `merge` and `dplyr` we can find a solution. Note that we set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in our `read.table` call.

#### Use `merge` and `dplyr`

```
# merge the tables
f1f2_merge <- merge(file1, file2, by = 'Chr')

#     Chr Pos DepthAverage Dispersion Start End
# 1  chr1   1            5          4     1   4
# 2  chr1   1            5          4     5   6
# 3  chr1   2            4          1     1   4
# ...


library(dplyr)

f1f2_merge %>%
    filter(Pos >= Start & Pos <= End) %>%        # matches condition
    group_by(Chr, Start, End) %>%                # group appropriately
    summarise(DepthAverage = mean(DepthAverage), # perform calculations
              Dispersion = mean(Dispersion))

#     Chr Start   End DepthAverage Dispersion
#   <chr> <int> <int>        <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1  chr1     1     4         5.25       4.25
# 2  chr1     5     6         3.50       5.00
# 3  chr2     1     2         1.00       3.50
# 4  chr2     3     3         3.00       3.00
```

#### Use `plyr::adply` and `dplyr`

To avoid using `merge` we can use the `adply` function from the **`plyr`** package, and then do some manipulation using the **`dplyr`** package. **Note that you should load `plyr` PRIOR to loading `dplyr`.**

We iterate over the rows of `file2`, and select the matching rows (same `Chr` and `Pos` between `Start` and `End`) in `file1`. Then, we perform our calculations on the matching rows.

```
library(plyr); library(dplyr)

adply(file2, 1, .fun = function(d){
    file1 %>%
        filter(Chr == d$Chr & Pos >= d$Start & Pos <= d$End) %>%
        summarise('DepthAverage' = mean(DepthAverage), 
                  'Dispersion' = mean(Dispersion))
})

#    Chr Start End DepthAverage Dispersion
# 1 chr1     1   4         5.25       4.25
# 2 chr1     5   6         3.50       5.00
# 3 chr2     1   2         1.00       3.50
# 4 chr2     3   3         3.00       3.00
```

#### Data

You changed your data after asking the question, I have updated the data to reflect this.

```
file1 <-"Chr Pos DepthAverage Dispersion
chr1  1    5  4
chr1  2    4  1
chr1  3    5  3
chr1  4    7  9
chr1  5    4  8
chr1  6    3  2
chr2  1    1  3
chr2  2    1  4
chr2  3    3  3"

file1 <- read.table(text = file1, header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

file2 <-"Chr  Start  End
chr1  1  4
chr1  5  6
chr2  1  2
chr2  3  3"
file2 <- read.table(text = file2, header = T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer, but this merge doen´t work in my case, because my database is very large, so I have several lines (or intervals) with chr1 and several lines with chr2 and several with chr3 and so on within the file2. Would you have any other strategies to deal with this merge?

Comment: @Fpertille have you tried running my solution on the new data? It still works and matches your expected output.